# Circular primes under a certain number

Tags: python, primes

I wrote some code to find the circular prime numbers of a certain number which works fine on its own-

```
import sympy as sp
PrimeCount=0
i=0
Remainder=0
PrimeSum=0
N=input("Enter an integer number=")
length=len(N)
n=int(N)
while(i<length):
    Remainder=int(n % 10)
    n=int(n / 10)
    n=int((Remainder * (10 ** (length - 1)) + n))
    PrimeCount=(sp.isprime(n))
    if PrimeCount==False:
        PrimeCount=0
    else:
        PrimeCount=1
    PrimeSum=PrimeSum+PrimeCount
    i+=1
if(PrimeSum==length):
    print(N,"is a circular prime")
else:
    print(N,"is not a circular prime")
```

However when I implement the same code so that it gives me all the circular primes under an inputed number, it not working as intended as it keeps saying the only circular primes are 2 and 11. I genuinely don't know why this isn't working for me. Here's the code I'm having trouble with-

```
import sympy as sp
PrimceCount=0
i=0
Remainder=0
PrimeSum=0
mx=int(input())
SecondList=[]
Circ=[]
FirsList=list(range(0,(mx+1)))
for n1 in FirsList:
    if sp.isprime(n1)==True:
        SecondList.append(n1)
print(SecondList)
for n2 in SecondList:
    length=len(str(n2))
    n1=(n2)
    while(i<length):
        Remainder=int(n1 % 10)
        n1=int(n1 / 10)
        n1=int((Remainder * (10 ** (length - 1)) + n1))
        PrimeCount=(sp.isprime(n1))
        if PrimeCount==False:
            PrimeCount=0
        else:
            PrimeCount=1
        PrimeSum=PrimeSum+PrimeCount
        i+=1
        if(PrimeSum==length):
            Circ.append(n2)
enum=len(Circ)
print('Circ=',Circ)
print('There are',enum,'circular primes below', mx)
```

Comment: Explain "isn't working". What happens, what should happen? Do error messages appear?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Lack of effort on your part, doesn't lend itself to this site. This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: It's very hard to debug code when none of your variable names describe what they are. You'd also make your life easier if, once you have your code working to check circular primeness, you enclose it in a *function* that you can call on any number.

Comment: Please split your code into functions and use descriptive variable and function names.

Comment: You can weed out a lot of numbers without prime checking.  The only circular prime with the digit 5 is 5 itself.  Similarly for 2.  No circular prime can contain the digits 0, 4, 6 or 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `i` and `primeSum` for every new prime you check:

```py
for n2 in SecondList:
    PrimeSum=0                 # Reset PrimeSum
    length=len(str(n2))
    n1=(n2)
    i=0                        # Reset i
    while(i<length):
        Remainder=int(n1 % 10)
        n1=int(n1 / 10)
        n1=int((Remainder * (10 ** (length - 1)) + n1))
        PrimeCount=(sp.isprime(n1))
        if PrimeCount==False:
            PrimeCount=0
        else:
            PrimeCount=1
        PrimeSum=PrimeSum+PrimeCount
        i+=1
        if(PrimeSum==length):
            Circ.append(n2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's some code to use:

```py
def cyclic_permutations_of_string(s: str) -> list[str]:
    return [
        s[i:] + s[:i]
            for i in range(len(s))
    ]


def cyclic_permutations_of_number(n: int) -> list[int]:
    return [int(p) for p in cyclic_permutations_of_string(str(n))]


def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    i = 2
    while i**2 <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True


def is_circular_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    return all(is_prime(k) for k in cyclic_permutations_of_number(n))
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The asker *already* has code that correctly checks if a number is circularly prime. An alternate method to do so could be a useful part of an answer, but is not an answer in and of itself.

Comment: @CrazyChucky. It's not an answer to the question itself, but it might help the questioner to write better code.

Comment: Seems wasteful to always compute all permutations even when the first one already turns out to be not prime.

Comment: @KellyBundy. I made it a generator at first, but then decided to go with a list to make it easier for the asker who probably don't know of generators.